# Adding a user library to the Web Deployment Assembly will overwrite the contents of the WEB-INF directory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, publish

Using Eclipse Indigo, I have some user libraries that i'd like to deploy to tomcat. By default, the deployment assembly has `WebRoot -> /`, which is fine, except of course it won't deploy my user libs. If I were to publish at this point, it would fill the WebRoot/WEB-INF properly (sans the user libs).

However, if I add a user lib to the deployment assembly (add-> java build path entry), then when i publish, everything is removed from WebRoot/WEB-INF, and the only thing it contains is libs/(my user libs).

Why does adding a user lib to the deployment assembly nuke the WEB-INF directory? How can I get both my user libs and my WEB-INF content published?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a new assembly directive: `WebRoot/WEB-INF -> /WEB-INF` and that did the job. seems redundant - I wonder if this is a bug?